# Como crear un trigger MYSQL que guarde el usuario de sesión al actualizar una tabla?

Tags: mysql, nodejs, express, session

Estoy creando un trigger Mysql que registre los cambios en una tabla pero no he podido pasar la variable de sesión para incluír el usuario que hizo los cambios,acá está mi trigger que funciona pero me falta el dato del usuario:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER after_objetos_update
AFTER UPDATE
ON objetos FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    
        INSERT INTO registro
        VALUES(null,old.id_emp,sysdate(),/* acá el user */,old.ambito, old.objeto, old.json,new.json);
    
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Muy agradecido de antemano por cualquier ayuda

Comment: no entiendo si el problema es el query, o que no podes pasar desde node la variable de sesion.. en tal caso, el problema son dos cosas totalmente distintas...

Comment: Necesita algo para guardar el usuario que actualiza después en la tabla objeto yo le propuse usar ``user()`` dentro del insert que en mi ejemplo funciona @gbianchi aunque no se si estoy en lo cierto pero creo que si :)

Comment: @JavierG.Raya Le estoy pregunta a OP sobre que viene su pregunta. Vos entendiste algo, yo entiendo dos cosas distintas, entonces le pido que aclare...

Answer (score 0):

Para que se guarde en un registro con poner simplemente `USER()` te vale.

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER after_objetos_update
AFTER UPDATE
ON objetos FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    
        INSERT INTO registro
        VALUES(null,old.id_emp,sysdate(),USER(),old.ambito, old.objeto, old.json,new.json);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

[<kbd>Ejecutar Ejemplo</kbd>](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3PnzHErrf2fZFGZY67K12X/278)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta pero no es lo que buscaba dado que usando USER() solo me inserta el usuario de conexión a la base de datos,yo quiero insertar el usuario de la sesión  express...

Comment: @CristianGarate es decir te debe mostrar simplemente pepito por ejemplo y no pepito@locahost